# Is there a list of linux file descriptors somewhere?

Tags: linux

I'm having trouble finding them, and how to use them in general. for example i see in x86 functions, the output may be a file descriptor. i cant seem to find much about them on the web so im trying it here. and yes im very new to linux

Comment: File descriptor values have no inherent meaning so it doesn't really make sense to have a list of them. POSIX defines a few standard file descriptors such as STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. Is that what you are after? Can you please clarify what you expect to find in the list or what you actually need to know from that list?

Comment: I suppose I'm chasing after what they really are. I've never had to really deal with them until now lol

Comment: As far as user application code is concerned they are just opaque numbers. The kernel uses those numbers in its implementation to reference internal data structures that correspond to the stream that has been associated with that fd.

Comment: do you know why they would be called file descriptors? as in do they really have anything to do with files

Comment: sorry if i sound so nooblike but im very clueless about this topic

Comment: What is your understanding of the ways a program can get a file descriptor? If you can answer that then you can answer your own question.

Comment: A file descriptor is just an open file handle returned by `open()`, `pipe()`, `socket()` and such. To write to a file on disk, you call `open()` with a filename and get a file descriptor, then you pass that fd to `write()` to write data to it.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is about! File descriptors are local to a program, generated inside the program by calling library functions. What is the need of having a list of them and what is the target, if we have one. For me, this is an XY problem, isn't it? Please close the question as it is unclear what you really want to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of file descriptors is:

```
ls -l /proc/self/fd
```

Every process has its own list.

The following script will print all file descriptors of all processes.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

find /proc -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '/proc/[0-9]+' -printf '%P\n' |
  {
    while read -r pid; do
      if [[ -d /proc/$pid ]]; then
        printf '%d:' "$pid"
        find /proc/"$pid"/fd -type l -printf ' %P' 2>/dev/null
        printf '\n'
      fi
    done
  }
```

You need `root` permissions to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

A file descriptor is basically just an integer. It gets returned by certain functions, e.g. open().

It is used very similar to a pointer in C, you don't do much with it except pass it to other functions, e.g. read(). I don't think doing pointer arithmetic on file handles makes that much sense, though. The fstat() system call will return you a bunch of information about the file. See the manpage:

```
man 2 fstat
```

Each process has its own list of file handles, the numbering always starts at 0 for STDIN, 1 for STDOUT and 2 for STDERR, then continues simply counting up as you open and close files.

Except for the first three, that number has no deeper meaning, it just tells the kernel which one from its list of open files it should operate on. The concept seems to be so simple that nobody has bothered to document it... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a list of linux file descriptors somewhere?

Yes, the kernel maintains a **list of open file descriptors per process.**  This is the reason you don't find it in internet (it is very dynamic).  The ones a process always receives already open, when the program starts are: 0 (standard input); 1 (standard output); and 2 (standard error).  This is the mechanism employed in unix systems to allow the parent process to redirect standard input, standard output or standard error.  Other file descriptor numbers are assigned/created by the kernel when you `open()` a file, create a *socket* with `socket()` system call, `pipe()` system call, or some other way (there are many)

A file descriptor *per se* is just a unique number (each process has a set of distinct numbers) the kernel uses to convey with the process a reference to a kernel resource (like a name) that the program is going to use.  When you `open()` a file, you provide a name and the way you are going to access it (read only, read/write, write only or none -- this last to deal with resources that don't allow you to read/write them, like directories or the like) and receive in exchange a descriptor number that will be used in all the calls related to that file/socket/etc.

Comment: This problem originally arose when I was trying to bind a socket. This may be off topic to my original question, but do I need to use the socket fd to bind it?

Comment: You need to bind a socket to assign it a local port and address if your socket is for a server that needs these to be contacted.  But binding ocurrs automatically if you have not done it prior to connect().  An excellent book for this is Unix Network Programming, by the passed excellent guy Richard Stevens.  You can find it [here](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/W-Richard-Stevens/dp/0131411551/)

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful. have a good day

Comment: @Mr_Arsonist, Upvoting the answer (or even selecting it as the _selected answer_) is a way to notice the helpfullness of the answer. Don't hesitate and upvote/select it.

Comment: i dont have enough karma to upvote yet lol